# Error while restoring a Database from an SQL dump

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, restore

I am  extremely new to MySQL and am running it on Windows. I am trying to restore a Database from a dumpfile in MySQL, but I get the following error:

```
$ >mysql -u root -p -h localhost -D database -o < dump.sql
ERROR: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: 'SQLite format 3'.
```

I tried `$ > mysql -u root -p -h localhost -D database --binary-mode -o < dump.sql` but this gave me the following `ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\☻'.` 
It is a 500 Mb dump file, and when I view its contents using gVIM, all I can see is expressions and data which is not comprehensible. Also when I try to copy contents from the file to post here all I can copy is :`SQLite format 3` This kind of seems strange.

Answer (score 21):

The reference to [`--binary-mode`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_binary-mode) (introduced in MySQL 5.6.3) is probably a distraction.

It doesn't sound like you're dealing with a mysqldump output file, there.  Try the `file` utility.

```
shell> file dumpfile.sql
dumpfile.sql: ASCII text
```

If you don't get the `ASCII text` response, you're dealing with either something that isn't a dump file from `mysqldump` at all, or you're dealing with something that's been compressed (with gzip or bzip2, for example), which you'd need to uncompress before piping it into `mysql`.

If you see `SQLite 3.x database` then you definitely have your answer... it's a raw SQLite database, not a MySQL dump file.

Indeed, the first few bytes of a SQLite database are these:

```
53 51 4C 69 74 65 20 66  SQLite f
6F 72 6D 61 74 20 33 00  ormat 3^@
```

Note that the 16th octet here is 0x00, explaining the `ERROR: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement...` message in this case.  The suggestion that `--binary-mode` is appropriate is a false alarm.

---

Windows users: the 'file' utility is a tool from Unix, but the Windows version can be found [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm).

Answer (score 9):

## Windows

Create your dump files with this command

```
.\mysqldump [dbname] -r [filename.sql]
```

**Using:**

```
.\mysqldumb --help
```

> -r, --result-file=name

```
                 Direct output to a given file. This option should be used
                 in systems (e.g., DOS, Windows) that use carriage-return
                 linefeed pairs (\r\n) to separate text lines. This option
                 ensures that only a single newline is used.
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Powershell's >  creates UTF-16 encoded file that is causing problems. Search for Powershell here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 1):

I had this error once, after running `mysqldump` on Windows PowerShell like so:

```
mysqldump -u root p my_db --no-data --no-create-db --no-create-info --routines --triggers --skip-opt --set-gtid-purged=OFF > db_objects.sql
```

What I did was change it to this (pipe instead to Set-Content):

```
mysqldump -u root p my_db --no-data --no-create-db --no-create-info --routines --triggers --skip-opt --set-gtid-purged=OFF | Set-Content db_objects.sql
```

And the problem went away!

Answer (score 1):

**Me too in PowerShell**

I encountered this issue when I was using PowerShell to call ***mysqldump*** and ***>*** to pipe the output to file. PowerShell was using the incorrect encoding when creating the file and I was presented with the same error when I tried to import the file using *mysql .. < exported-file.sql*

I found that setting the default encoding to UTF8 in the PowerShell session resolved this problem.

**My resolution - Tested PowerShell 5.1:**

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues["Out-File:Encoding"] = "utf8";
```

**Example: How I was producing the export *(simplified)*:**

```
$cmdExportDB = "mysqldump --host $Host --databases $DbName -u $UID =p$PWD > $fileName";
Invoke-Expression "& $cmdExportDB";
```

**Note: Discovered this does not work on PowerShell 4.0**

My development environment was running 5.1, but prod is at 4.0 and my initial fix does not work in older versions of PowerShell.

Need to use 
`| Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 $fileName`

This was already suggested by Ifedi

Answer (score 0):

Someone sent me a compressed gtar. Wasn't even too familiar with gtar, but it is another compression format.

```
$ file core_production-1432173533.sql.gtar
core_production-1432173533.sql.gtar: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Wed May 20 21:59:31 2015
```

However, I was able to decompress it the same as usual:

```
tar -zxvf core_production-1432173533.sql.gtar
$ file core_production-1432173533.sql
core_production-1432173533.sql: ASCII text, with very long lines
```

And then I could do the import:

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost core_production < core_production-1432173533.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** Extract the backup file and then restore this extracted sql dump.

Example :

Backup has been taken as dump.sql.gz file and extract it using gunzip cmd as follows,

```
shell>  gunzip dump.sql.gz
```

And RESTORE extracted dump.sql file.

Ref: About MySQL binary and interactive mode.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_binary-mode

It Works for me and All set !!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the file was corrupted. The database was compressed with extension `.bz2` but it was actually a `.tar.bz2`.

Decomprossing using `bzip2 -dk` doesn't output any error and generates the file. Using the command `file` on the file outputs `bzip2 compressed data, block size = 900k` so it doesn't even looks wrong to use it.

I had to use `tar -xf myfile.bz2`